# Enforcing use of format suffix patterns in DRF with ViewSets

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest Framework to make a read-only API from an existing Django website. I'd like to *require* API URLs to include a [format suffix](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/format-suffixes/) (either `.json`, or `.api` for the browsable API) but I can't see how to do this when using ViewSets and Routers.

In my main site `urls.py` I have:

```py
from django.urls import include

# ...

urlpatterns += [
    path("api/v1/", include("api.urls", namespace="v1")),
]
```

And `api/urls.py` contains:

```py
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from . import views

app_name = "api"

router = DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register(r"people", views.PersonViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path("", include(router.urls)),
]
```

Two issues:

1. I can get a browsable API page by going to either `/api/v1/people` or `/api/v1/people.api` – I'd like to *enforce* the use of the latter.
2. The `api-root` view is visible at `/api/v1/` or `/api/v1/.api`. That last looks ugly! But I can't see how to make it `/api/v1.api`, given I use a trailing slash on all URLs on the site, apart from the API.

Because I feel like I'm fighting DRF on this, I also feel I'm missing what the common best practice is.

Comment: Sorry that didn't work out for ya.  I think you are going to need to modify one of the default routers, either way, since this isn't default supported behavior.  Maybe a little more involved than my hack, but thats just normal.

Comment: After all `DefaultRouter` is just derived from `SimpleRouter` itself (and with a very misleading name).

Answer (score 0):

At Andrew Backer's suggestion I tried using my own version of `DefaultRouter` and have, I think, solved point (1).

If I copy [`DefaultRouter`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/0323d6f8955f987771269506ca5da461e2e7a248/rest_framework/routers.py#L302), give it a new name, and make a single change, it enforces the use of format extensions. The only change is in the `get_urls()` method, where I change this:

```py
        if self.include_format_suffixes:
            urls = format_suffix_patterns(urls)
```

To this:

```py
        if self.include_format_suffixes:
            urls = format_suffix_patterns(urls, suffix_required=True, allowed=["api", "json"])
```

The `suffix_required` argument is the trick. It's a shame there's no way to pass an argument into `DefaultRouter` in order to toggle this on or off.

I tried subclassing `DefaultRouter` and only overriding the `get_urls()` method (rather than entirely copying and replacing the class) but that generated ImproperlyConfigured exceptions, "…is not a valid regular expression: redefinition of group name 'format' as group 2; was group 1 at position 42". I think that results in `format_suffix_patterns()` getting called twice, [which is similar to an Issue here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/5628).